# Using layered rendering with default framebuffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, framebuffer

I know that we can attach a layered texture which is:

```
A mipmap level of a 1D/2D texture array
A mipmap levevl of a 3D texture
A mipmap levevl of a Cube Texture/ Cube Texture Array
```

to a FBO and do layered rendering.

The OpenGL wiki also says "Layered rendering is the process of having the GS send specific primitives to different layers of a layered framebuffer."

Can default framebuffer be a layered framebuffer? i.e Can I bind a 3d texture to the default FB and use a geometry shader to render to different layers of this texture?
I tried writing such a program but the screen is blank and I am not sure if this is right.

If it is not, what is possibly happening when I bind default FB for layered rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default framebuffer for layered rendering, then everything you draw will go straight to the default framebuffer. They will behave as if everything were in the same layer.

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Core Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - 9.8 Layered Framebuffers - pp. 296

> A framebuffer is considered to be layered if it is complete and all of its populated attachments are layered. When rendering to a layered framebuffer, each fragment generated by the GL is assigned a layer number.
>
> [...]
>
> ***A layer number written by a geometry shader has no effect if the framebuffer is not layered.***

Comment: So the conclusion is that default FB cannot be layered and hence gl_Layer has no effect?

Comment: That is correct, you may hear of something called layer planes from time to time especially in WGL, but that is not the same thing as a layered framebuffer as far as GL is concerned. You can only attach images to FBOs, so I am not sure how you are binding a 3D texture and attempting to draw into it using the default framebuffer.